# Prevent redirect to site.mobile.master

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2013

When I run the web form template of Visual Studio 2013 on a mobile phone the master page is redirected to Site.Mobile.master by default. Is there any way to prevent this and how???

THANKS

Answer (score 6):

you can fool the application adding the code below in your web.config inside

```
<system.web>
    <browserCaps>
        <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
    </browserCaps>
</system.web>
```

The code should be placed within the `<system.web>` tag. Your web.config file may already contain the tag, so can be placed in the existing one.